# Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘show’ prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved

Tags: haskell

I have a function that returns a list containing every other item from the original list starting with the first.

I'm getting the following error:

`Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘show’ prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved. Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.`

```
everyOtherInit orig pos acc = do
  let (head:tail) = orig
  if orig == [] then acc
  else if (rem pos 2) == 1 then everyOtherInit tail (pos+1) (acc ++ head)
  else everyOtherInit tail (pos+1) acc

everyOther orig = everyOtherInit orig 1 []
...
putStrLn (show(everyOther [1,2,3]))
```

I've tried using a type annotation `putStrLn (show(everyOther [1,2,3]::[Num]))` but that still doesn't solve the issue.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't leave out type annotations as they reveal very useful information:

```hs
everyOtherInit :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> Integer -> [a] -> [a]
everyOtherInit orig pos acc = do
  let (head:tail) = orig
  if orig == [] then acc
  else if (rem pos 2) == 1 then everyOtherInit tail (pos+1) (acc ++ head)
  else everyOtherInit tail (pos+1) acc

everyOther :: [[a]] -> [a]
everyOther orig = everyOtherInit orig 1 []
```

This reveals some troubling things. First of all, why does `everyOtherInit` need `Eq a`? It's because you check if `orig == []`. You can fix this simply by using the dedicated function, `null`. Next, the first parameter is `[[a]]` instead of `[a]`. Why? Because you have `(acc ++ head)` when `++` is used to concatenate lists. It should be `(acc ++ [head])`. Here's the fixed code:

```hs
everyOtherInit :: [a] -> Integer -> [a] -> [a]
everyOtherInit orig pos acc = do
  let (head:tail) = orig
  -- orig == [] becomes null orig
  if null orig then acc
  -- acc ++ head becomes acc ++ [head]
  else if (rem pos 2) == 1 then everyOtherInit tail (pos+1) (acc ++ [head])
  else everyOtherInit tail (pos+1) acc

everyOther :: [a] -> [a]
everyOther orig = everyOtherInit orig 1 []
```

Comment: That fixed it. I'm still getting used to the Haskell's type system so appreciate your comments :)